# Differences between complex number implementations in Haskell and Python

Tags: python, haskell, complex-numbers

I'm trying to map the complex number functionality in Python, to `Data.Complex` in Haskell, but I've reached a point where they differ, and I am unsure as to why.

In python:

```
>>> x = 3j
3j
>>> x.real
0.0
>>> x.imag
3.0
```

In Haskell:

```
> import Data.Complex
> let j n = 0 :+ n
> let x = j 3.0
> realPart x
0.0
> imagPart x
3.0
```

So far they look the same. Looks like operating on them doesn't differ much either:

Python:

```
>>> y = 1 + x
(1+3j)
>>> y.real
1.0
>>> y.imag
3.0
```

Haskell:

```
> let y = 1 + x
> realPart y
1.0
> imagPart y
3.0
```

In isolation `+ - * / **` all seem to work the same way. However this operation yields two different results:

```
>>> z = (y - 1) ** 2
(-9+0j)
>>> z.real
-9.0
>>> z.imag
0.0
```

But in Haskell:

```
> let z = (y - 1) ** 2
> realPart z
-9.000000000000002
> imagPart z
1.1021821192326181e-15
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Haskell, `(**)` for `Complex` is essentially

```
a ** b = exp (b * log a)
```

which has many opportunities for bad rounding errors to creep in. (I don't know enough Python to check what it would do with an analogous log-then-exp expression; the thing I tried complained that it wasn't ready to handle `log(3j)`.) It has a bunch of special cases to thwart rounding errors, but none check for a fully-real integer exponent. You might consider this a bug or infelicity and report it to the folks in charge of the `Complex` type as another special case worth adding to the implementation of `(**)`.

In the meantime, if you know your exponent is integral, you can use `(^)` (for positive numbers only) or `(^^)` instead:

```
Data.Complex> (0 :+ 3) ^ 2
(-9.0) :+ 0.0
```

Comment: The `cmath` module in Python provides a [complex-aware](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/cmath.html#power-and-logarithmic-functions) `log` function. I'm taking a look at the source now.

Comment: @senderle Nice. With `from cmath import log, exp`, I get `exp(2 * log(3j))` printing out exactly what Haskell printed for `(0 :+ 3) ** 2`.

Comment: `Data.Complex` is in `base`, so bugs should be reported on the GHC Trac system with a "core libraries" component field.

Answer (score 4):

Although the results given by the two languages are different, they aren't *very* different (as others have indicated in the comments). So you might guess that it's just a matter of slightly different implementations -- and you'd be right.

[Daniel Wagner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48101023/577088) indicates that in Haskell, the `**` operator is defined as

```
a ** b = exp (b * log a)
```

Haskell does some special casing, but most of the time, the operation relies on the general-purpose definitions of `exp` and `log` for complex numbers.

In Python, it's a little different: powers are calculated using a *polar* representation. This approach involves using a different set of general-purpose functions -- most of them basic trigonometric functions over ordinary floating point numbers -- and does almost no special-casing. It's not clear to me that this approach is better overall, but it does happen to give a more correct answer in the particular case you've chosen.

Here's the [core of the implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Objects/complexobject.c#L125-L134):

```
vabs = hypot(a.real,a.imag);
len = pow(vabs,b.real);
at = atan2(a.imag, a.real);
phase = at*b.real;
if (b.imag != 0.0) {
    len /= exp(at*b.imag);
    phase += b.imag*log(vabs);
}
r.real = len*cos(phase);
r.imag = len*sin(phase);
```

Here, `a` is the base and `b` is the exponent. `vabs` and `at` give the polar representation of `a`, such that

```
a.real = vabs * cos(at)
a.imag = vabs * sin(at)
```

And as you can see in the last two lines of code, `len` and `phase` give the corresponding polar representation of the result, `r`.

When `b` is real, the `if` block isn't executed, and this simplifies to [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula). I can't find a canonical formula covering the complex or imaginary cases, but it appears to be pretty simple!